# Detect iOS network setting change?

Tags: ios

The first launching  after my app is installed in device will always load failed  from internet, because the the user hasn't grant the app any permission to use the WLAN or Cellular access . So i want to do some improve on this , and I want to refresh loading  after the user grant the permisson  to the app after dismiss the permisson dialog , Is there any callback or notification to do this kind of refresh ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Apps do not require user permission on iOS to access the Internet via wifi or cellular networks. In iOS 14 permission is required to discover local devices using bonjour.

Comment: @Paulw11, When you install a app , and open it the first time , the iOS will present a alert for you to picking WIFI or Celluar permission .

Comment: I have never seen that. Only the new prompt that requests access to the local network if you use bonjour.